# How to set up automatic mounting of network share

Tags: shared-folders

I need to automatically mount a network share to a mount point whenever I log into my computer. Currenlty I am doing this manually by running through my history to run the command again and again.

sudo mount IPADDRESS:/path/todir path/to/local/mount/point

How can this be done?

Comment: What sort of share is this? NFS? Samba?

Comment: NFS. The directory is on a ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

But the key part is this

> Add a line at the bottom of your /etc/fstab file that specifies:
>
> //$SERVER/$SHARE $MOUNTPOINT $FS_TYPE
>   credentials=$SMB_CREDENTIALS,uid=$UID,gid=$GID

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line to your [`/etc/fstab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) file. For `fstab` entries, you can use the `auto` or `noauto` option to let your system mount the remote filesystem automatically on boot or on `mount -a`, or to prohibit automounting. AFAIK `auto` is the default.